# Is it possible to add progress-bar to a function in existing R package

Tags: r

I am using the R package minerva for scaling up the computation of Maximal Information based Nonparametric Exploration (MINE). Looking at the code, it seems that vectorized computations are being perfomed through a function like this

```
return(.allvsallparall(x, alpha, C, eps, n.cores))
```

Since this is computationally expensive, I would like to see the progress of the running code. Is it possible (other than benchmarking on smaller data and extrapolation) to add a progress bar to an existing function in the package without breaking the code?

Comment: You can use `Rprof` to get a breakdown of the timings for each individual process in a function

Comment: R has a progress bar, there is a package called `pbapply` that wraps the progress bar into the apply family. BUT, this can almost double the computing time.